# Find the same number in two arrays and place it into a new array

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers, duplicates, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection between two sets and the numbers that match will go into a new set but my code isn't working.

```
public static int intersection (int[] setA, int sizeA, int[]
    setB, int sizeB, int[] resultSet) 
{
    int copies = 0;

    for(int count = 0; count < sizeA; count++) 
    {
        for(int x= 0; count < sizeB; x++) 
        {
            if(setA[count] == setB[x])
            {
                resultSet[copies] = setB[x]; 
                copies++;
            }
        }
    }
    return copies; 
}
```

Comment: Looks like a type: `for(int x=0; x<sizeB; x++)`

Answer (score 0):

If this is for homework, this probably won't help you. But otherwise, LINQ will do this extremely nicely.

```
public static int[] intersection (int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB)
{
    return setA.Take(sizeA).Intersect(setB.Take(sizeB)).ToArray();
}
```

I left in the `sizeA` and `sizeB` and left everything as arrays, although I'd take those out and change it to `IEnumerable<int>` in production, or better yet just use the [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx) call directly.

Note, of course, that this doesn't depend on them being in the same order, as it looks like yours is trying to do. I'm assuming that isn't intended, because that raises some logical difficulties that you haven't addressed.

Beyond this, I really need more information about the requirements. Your title doesn't really make a lot of sense, so I'm going off of some assumptions about what you'd like, that might not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
int[] SetA = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] SetB = { 1, 3, 5, 10 };

var Temp = SetA.Intersect(SetB);

int[] SetC = Temp.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop you are incrementing x outside the array length, so changing the code as per below should fix that:

```
public static int intersection(int[] setA, int sizeA, int[] setB, int sizeB, int[] resultSet)
    {
        int copies = 0;

        for (int count = 0; count < sizeA; count++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < sizeB; x++)
            {
                if (setA[count] == setB[x])
                {
                    resultSet[copies] = setB[x];
                    copies++;
                }
            }
        }
        return copies;
    }
```